# Beginner Python Monte Carlo Simulation

Tags: python, montecarlo

I'm a beginner at Python and am working through exercises set by our instructor. I am struggling with this question.

In the Python editor, write a Monte Carlo simulation to estimate the value of the number π.
Specifically, follow these steps:
A. Produce two arrays, one called x, one called y, which contain 100 elements each,
which are randomly and uniformly distributed real numbers between -1 and 1.
B. Plot y versus x as dots in a plot. Label your axes accordingly.
C. Write down a mathematical expression that defines which (x, y) pairs of data points
are located in a circle with radius 1, centred on the (0, 0) origin of the graph.
D. Use Boolean masks to identify the points inside the circle, and overplot them in a
different colour and marker size on top of the data points you already plotted in B.

This is what I have at the moment.

```
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
np.random.seed(12345)
x = np.random.uniform(-1,1,100) 
y = np.random.uniform(-1,1,100) 
plt.plot(x,y) //this works


for i in x:
    newarray = (1>math.sqrt(y[i]*y[i] + x[i]*x[i]))
plt.plot(newarray)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `for i in x:` probably you meant `for i in range(len(x)):`. However, you don't need the `for` loop, you can do `mask = 1 > np.sqrt(y *y + x * x)`. This will give you a boolean array that you can use to pick the elements inside the circle (e.g. `x[mask]`, `y[mask]`) to draw them again in a different color. Btw, you may prefer `plt.scatter` instead of `plt.plot` to draw point clouds.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

as pointed out in the comment the error in your code is `for i in x` should be `for i in xrange(len(x))`

If you want to actually use a Boolean mask as said in the statement you could do something like this

```py
    import pandas as pd
    allpoints = pd.DataFrame({'x':x, 'y':y})

    # this is your boolean mask
    mask = pow(allpoints.x, 2) + pow(allpoints.y, 2) < 1
    circlepoints = allpoints[mask]

    plt.scatter(allpoints.x, allpoints.y)
    plt.scatter(circlepoints.x, circlepoints.y)
```

increasing the number of point to 10000 you would get something like this
[image: scatter plot]

to estimate PI you can use the famous montecarlo derivation

```
    >>> n = 10000
    >>> ( len(circlepoints) * 4 ) / float(n)
    <<< 3.1464
```

Answer (score 4):

You are close to the solution. I slightly reshape your MCVE:

```
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(12345)

N = 10000
x = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, N) 
y = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, N)
```

Now, we compute a criterion that makes sense in this context, such as the distance of points to the origin:

```
d = x**2 + y**2
```

Then we use [Boolean Indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays) to discriminate between points within and outside the Unit Circle:

```
q = (d <= 1)
```

At this point lies the Monte Carlo Hypothesis. We assume the ratio of uniformly distributed points in the Circle and in the plane `U(-1,1)xU(-1,1)` is representative for the Area of the Unit Circle and the Square. Then we can statistically assess `pi = 4*(Ac/As)` from the ratio of points within the Circle/Square. This leads to:

```
pi = 4*q.sum()/q.size # 3.1464
```

Finally we plot the result:

```
fig, axe = plt.subplots()
axe.plot(x[q], y[q], '.', color='green', label=r'$d \leq 1$')
axe.plot(x[~q], y[~q], '.', color='red', label=r'$d > 1$')
axe.set_aspect('equal')
axe.set_title(r'Monte Carlo: $\pi$ Estimation')
axe.set_xlabel('$x$')
axe.set_ylabel('$y$')
axe.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1), loc='upper left')
fig.savefig('MonteCarlo.png', dpi=120)
```

It outputs:

[image]